# Can't find "Choose Icon" in Qt Creator 4.5.0

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm a beginner at Qt. I followed the instructions on https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qtquick-iso-icon-browser.html and tried to browse ISO 7000 Icons, but there is no "Choose Icon" on my right-click menu.

I created an empty Qt Quick application, opened main.qml, went to design mode, imported a few things including quickextras 1.4, dragged "picture" then right-clicked on it, What did I miss? Thank you!
[The screen shot is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYzos.jpg)

The main.qml is as simple as this:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import QtCharts 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import Qt3D.Extras 2.9

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    color: "#a4a7a8"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Picture {
        id: picture
        x: 191
        y: 171
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: **You can add icons from an ISO 7000 icon library that is installed with Qt Creator to Qt Quick applications (commercial only).** Are you using commercial build of Qt? Have you downloaded commercial Extras package?

Comment: Do you have a commertial licence of Qt?

Comment: Oh I'm using community version. Thank you pointing that out.@DmitrySazonov @Xplatforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a commercial feature and can't be used in community version, Thanks for pointing out!